# Applying aliases on conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Publishers` with a column `State`.

The question is to retrieve state of publishers and any state of publishers with null value show it as `(No state)`.

I tried using the condition

```
WHERE state IS NULL AS No_State
```

but I think the syntax is wrong - could someone help?

Thank you in advance

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 2):

```
select nvl( state, 'No State' ) from publishers
```

(edit) in sql server

```
SELECT COALESCE(state, 'No State') FROM publishers;
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, with a single column to check, you can use the (slightly) optimised *IsNull* function:

```
Select isnull(state, '(No state)') as State
From Publishers
```

This is equivalent to using a `case` or `inline if` expression such as

```
Select case when state is null then '(No state)' else state end as State
from Publishers
```